# Exporting to xlsx in sql developer

Tags: excel, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am exporting a small file, **8mb** from **SQL** developer to **xlsx**.
It is taking forever (freezing). I ran the same query in **Toad** and exported it with no issues.

Any idea on why developer doesn't seem to be working right?

Why does it show the log also?

It used to never show this.

[image]

Also, I used to be able to double click on a word in the SQL and it would highlight all the same values. It does not do that anymore.

What setting can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As of being unable to export data in XLSX format: try to export to a **CSV** file; Excel opens it easily so - if it works OK, just save the file to Excel format once you have data in it.

As of highlighting all occurrences of the selected word: enter "**Search**" mode (Ctrl + F). A search toolbar opens on a top of the editor window. Check toolbar buttons (point each of them with a mouse and hold it for a second, until the tooltip appears) - one of these (on my 17.3 version, it is a "yellow-ish" button) is the "**Highlight Occurrences**". I presume that it is *disabled* in your SQL Develoeper, so - enable it.